How to perform a 301 redirect from one domain to another in .NET?
I want to redirect my website traffic to www.example.com.
I have a web application that can be accessed in four different ways, these are through example.com, example.somee.com and the www version of both. The domain my page uses by default is example.somee.com, but I want to redirect all traffic to www.example.com. So far I've only been able to redirect to the www version from non-www with this:
<rule name="Redirect to www" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="*" />
   <conditions>
   <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="example.com" />
      </conditions>
   <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>

The rule for redirecting from example.somee.com to the desired site is this:
<rule name="Redirect to site" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="*" />
   <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="example.somee.com" />
   </conditions>
   <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>

When I try to access my page from that domain I receive an HTTP 400 error since in my appsettings.json file the value of the allowed hosts field is www.example.com. Am I writing my instructions wrong? What would be the correct way to redirect to the intended domain?

Based on your shared code snippet, to redirect traffic from multiple domains to www.example.com using .NET, configure URL Rewrite rules in your web.config file. Consolidate your redirection rules into one, specifying conditions to match example.com and example.somee.com, and redirect them to https://www.example.com/{R:0} with a 301 permanent redirect type. Ensure your appsettings.json includes all relevant domains in the AllowedHosts setting (example.com, example.somee.com, www.example.com) to avoid HTTP 400 errors.
